# MVC# Linq to SQL SubmitChanges Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have the following code - truck_mng is a record that as the data I need to update:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(Truck_Mng truck_mng) 
    {       
      if (ModelState.IsValid)       
      { 
       DataContext.SubmitChanges();           
       return RedirectToAction("Index");       
      }  
      return RedirectToAction("index");
```

}

The record does not get updated. Any idea? The table does have a primary key.

Comment: I don't see any changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess Truck_Mng is an entity class from you DataContext?

You hve to attach the entity first to your DataContext, because the modelbinder of the MVC framework just creates a new instance of that class to pass the form data to your action.

By setting the second parameter to `true`, you tell L2S that the entity is in modified state, but that only works when you have a timestamp member for version checking on your entity.

The simplest approach wiould be to attach as unmodified and then call `Refresh`. That way L2S checks for modifications and you can save your changed:

```
DataContext.Truck_Mng.Attach(truck_mng);
DataContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, truck_mng);
DataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - I get the following - An entity can only be attached as modified without original state if it declares a version member or does not have an update check policy.

Comment: Jan, it say RefreshMode does not exist in the current context. I am missing anything else? Is there a using at the top that I may need?

Comment: You need to say `using System.Data.Linq`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.linq.refreshmode.aspx